# Extracting ERROR section from the java log file using python

Tags: java, python, spring, logging

I would like to extract all the error section from java log file using python on hourly basis and  email the error section to concerned team members. I want skip the previous hour error section as well.

Here is my sample log file:

```
2020-03-19 03:31:10.299  INFO [foo-service,,,] 11 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2020-03-19 04:20:11.942  ERROR [foo-service,8ca1dc1d81dd6c80,8ca1dc1d81dd6c80,false] 11 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: InvalidGrantException, Bad credentials

org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidGrantException: Bad credentials
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.getOAuth2Authentication(ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

2020-03-19 05:16:10.432  INFO [foo-service,,,] 11 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2020-03-19 05:16:19.284  ERROR [foo-service,cbf09d934052fdae,cbf09d934052fdae,false] 11 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: InternalAuthenticationServiceException, User is Disabled

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: User is Disabled
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.getOAuth2Authentication(ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.java:71)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException: User is Disabled
    at com.kredifi.service.common.user.impl.PersonUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(PersonUserDetailsService.java:75)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108)
    ... 109 common frames omitted

2020-03-19 05:16:56.057 ERROR [foo-service,c90fd1cb11f1cc8d,c90fd1cb11f1cc8d,false] 11 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: InternalAuthenticationServiceException, User is Disabled

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: User is Disabled
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException: User is Disabled
    at com.kredifi.service.common.user.impl.PersonUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(PersonUserDetailsService.java:75)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108)
    ... 109 common frames omitted

2020-03-19 05:16:10.432  INFO [foo-service,,,] 11 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
```

Comment: Is python a strong requirement ? To me, this problem seems more suited for classic bash scripting with a cron job.

Comment: Could you provide us some example of what you've done to solve the problem so far, then we might be able to assist you by giving you advice on how to improve your code.

Comment: @Lescurel, Python is preferred. Even shell script will also do.